# Debugging WindowsPhoneTestFramework AutomationClient

Tags: windows-phone-7, wp7test

I've used the WindowsPhoneTestFramework and is great but it does not support some of the features that I need like setting the Width and Height of an element of changing the Layout of the Emulator for testing in Landscape and portrait, etc. While trying to add simple Commands Like Width and Height for some reason it is not working and here it comes the need to debug the AutomationClient.
For example I need to see what is happening in SetWidthCommand that I have created in WindowsPhoneTestFramework.Client.AutomationClient.Remote and understand why the property is not updated in the application under test.

I have created the SetWidth command and call from the console like: setWidth id=widthValue

I can debug until I get to ApplicationAutomationController where the command with 
AutomationIdentifier and value is created and after the SyncExecuteCommand I get the result as false.This means that something is wrong in the Client, so how do I debug the SetWidthCommand in Client.AutomationClient.Remote
This is the SetWidthCommand in Client.AutomationClient.Remote

```
public partial class SetWidthCommand
{
    protected override void DoImpl()
    {

        var element = GetUIElement();
        if (element == null)
            return;

        if (AutomationElementFinder.SetElementProperty(element, "Width", Value))
        {
            SendSuccessResult();
            return;
        }
        //setWidth ContentPanel 400
        if (ValueCommandHelper.TrySetValue(element, Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            SendSuccessResult();
            return;
        }
        // if width is missing... then give up
        SendNotFoundResult();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: can ypu explain more about what you mean by 'it is not working'? edit the question to explain what happens - do you see an exception? does it not start? does it start but ot hit breakpoints? will try to help :)

Comment: What question are you asking? Stackoverflow is *brilliant* for asking and answering questions. Please don't leave comments, instead edit the text to ask a question - a sentence that says "Why?", "How?", or "What?" (I am trying to help - honestly!)

Comment: I'm still not sure what your question is... but I've tried to explain some points below - if these don't help... please ask a "How?" question - as I really don't understand what you are asking :(

Answer (score 1):

The framework works by:

**The host**

- the test host is either a specflow script or a console application
- this test host provides a HTTP server providing a WCF Service - https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Server/WCFHostedAutomationController/Service/IPhoneAutomationService.cs
- the main method provided here are `GetNextCommand` and `SubmitResult`

  - `GetNextCommand` returns any of the classes derived from `CommandBase` - one of these classes - https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/tree/master/Server/WCFHostedAutomationController/Commands
  - `SubmitResult` expects any of the classes derived from `ResultBase` - one of these classes - https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/tree/master/Server/WCFHostedAutomationController/Results

**The client**

- the client runs on a thread within the app
- the client connects to the service and then polls continuously for Commands
- when the client receives a Command it processes the command using the 'partial class' part of the code - e.g. in https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/tree/master/Client/AutomationClient/Remote
- as part of that processing, the client must always return a Result to the service

**To add a Command or Result**

Because this mechanism uses WCF, then if you want to add a new Command or a new Result to the processing, then you will first need to add these to the Host, then you will need to update the client code - to do this you will need to use the Visual Studio tools to update the auto-generated WCF classes in https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/tree/master/Client/AutomationClient/Service%20References

This WCF update can be quite fiddly to do - but it's "normal" WCF operation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Once these are updated, then you can write the partial class code for your new Command in the Client.

**An alternative**

As an alternative approach, there is a 'generic' Command and Result pair available -

- GenericCommand https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Server/WCFHostedAutomationController/Commands/GenericCommand.cs
- SuccessResult - the "ResultText" can be used for any message - https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Server/WCFHostedAutomationController/Results/SuccessResult.cs

If you wish to use these, then Generic commands are passed through to the handlers registered statically in https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Client/AutomationClient/Remote/GenericCommand.cs

e.g. you could register something like:

```
GenericCommand.AddHandlerFactory("MyKey", (command, action) => {
    return (command) => {
        var result = new SuccessResult() {ResultText = "some example text" };
        result.Send(command.Configuration);
    };
});
```

This would be used to handle any GenericCommand with a `pleaseDo` field of "MyKey"

**Debugging**

From your question, I'm assuming you are already debugging the host successfully.

The easiest way to debug the client side is to:

- start the host first (e.g. the console in a debugger)
- then start the app in the debugger - it should start and connect to the WCF service within the host.

  - You can set breakpoints normally within your Command partial classes.
  - The main Run loop is in https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Client/AutomationClient/AutomationClient.cs
  - `GetAndProcessNextCommand` is the core of the processing cycle in the Run loop.

---

I hope that helps... if not, maybe try posting a larger code sample (maybe using gist or github)

Comment: Yes, Thank you, that was my question and I did all the above except the **Debugging** part I was not able to do. Problem solved , i can debug the client now :)

Comment: :) If it's the answer, please tick it to accept it - then others using stack overflow might benefit from it. Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: The code to register GenericCommand cannot compile. The error msg is "A local variable named command cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to command .... .... " What's wrong ?